# An embedded application for windows desktop using .NET platform?

Tags: c#, .net, embedded

I'm rebuilding an Embedded application:

*Prebuild application Specifications:*

> **Use** : For dispaying the captured images/video from microscope image capturing device on windows based PC or Laptops.
>
> **Sepcifications**: Prebuild on .NET plateform using VC++
>
> **Flaws** : Lacks some specified features.

*Current Requirement:*

> Want to rebuild that entire application using C# and add some additional client features.

*My Questions:*

> Is it feasible to develop such application in C#.net?
>
> If  yeh,What kind of resources available in C# to develop desktop embedded application?
>
> Any references which show any of such kind of application?
>
> Your suggestions on building this kind of application.
>
> P.S. It is essential to buid it on .NET platform.

Comment: What is an embedded desktop application?

Comment: He probably means http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/westandard/default.mspx Yes, Microsoft considers x86 hardware with > 1GB RAM "embedded" hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I think by "Prebuild" you mean "Existing". Why do you want to rewrite the complete application? As you have stated that the application is written in C++.Net. You can easily add all the new functions in C# and use that code from your existing C++.Net code.

Answer (score 0):

***Note:** I'm making this answer CW because the question is hard on the limit towards some close reasons. Everyone feel free to edit and extend it.*

> Is it feasible to develop such application in C#.net?

That's a tough one...from the top of my head I'd argue that it doesn't matter. If you know C#, then build it in C#, if the client wants it in C#, then build it in C#. You'll most likely have to use COM-Components or API-Invokes anyway to accomplish this.

If it is a TWAIN device, you might be better of to stick with VC++, I found TWAIN on .NET a real pain in the a** and have given up on such features. Same goes for WIA, but that might just be me.

> If yes, what kind of resources available in C# to develop desktop embedded application?

I guess you mean a Widget? In that case I have no idea, I never really looked at that (at least not on Windows). But as far as I know widgets on Windows consist of a data-backend and a HTML/JavaScript-Frontend, so you'll most likely have to develop the two separately.

> Any references which show any of such kind of application?

I guess any WIA/TWAIN application would be a reference, at least your description sounds so.

> Your suggestions on building this kind of application.

See your first question.